# Como abrir um arquivo que esta dentro da solução com o Process.Start()?

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, processo

Adicionei a minha solução em C# uma pasta chamada "arquivos" dentro dessa pasta serão colocados alguns documentos padrões que podem ser analisados na hora do cadastro de alguns projetos.

Eu tenho uma `ComboBox` no formulário para a pessoa escolher o arquivo que deseja abrir.

Eu estou tentando usar esse código:

```
Process.Start("../arquivos/teste.jpg");
```

Porém da erro. Ele não encontra o diretório. Queria saber se tem como colocar o caminho desta maneira usando `Process.Start()`.

Comment: como você está preenchendo o *ComboBox* com os arquivos? Qual o erro você recebe ao executar `Process.Start(...)`?

Comment: sobre isto, está certinho ele está identificando o valor e sabe qual é o arquivo selecionado. O erro é "Arquivo não encontrado." Porque o caminho não está completo(ex.: C:\\Arquivos\teste.jpg) só que eu não queria que ficasse assim... queria que fosse um caminho de dentro da solução pra que pudesse ser feito da maneira como fiz na pergunta

Comment: Eu posso quase te garantir que o endereço do arquivo está errado mesmo. Não vejo outro problema. Apesar que você pode estar achando que está em um diretório e estar em outro. Mande imprimir `Environment.CurrentDirectory` para ver se você está onde acha que deveria, caso contrário ter á que mudar ou informar onde está. Ou usar o caminho completo.

Comment: Sim vc está certo em um ponto o endereço atual é : (C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SLN_CAPRO\CAPRO\bin\Debug) e o que eu quero seria (C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SLN_CAPRO\CAPRO\arquivos\teste.jpg) tem algum jeito de eu abrir o arquivo sem precisar passar o caminho completo?

Comment: Dá vou tentar responder. Mas que mal lhe pergunte, poque você está tentando executar uma imagem? :)

Comment: A imagem é só um teste, o que será executado será um PDF com alguns padrões de projeto

Comment: Deu na mesma :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja bem, se você quer fazer uma aplicação que funcione em todas as situações precisa garantir que ela funcione em todas situações. Se não está achando o arquivo que você quer é provável que ele não exista mesmo. Pelo menos não no lugar onde está procurando.

Eu poderia mostrar como acessar o diretório desejado de uma outra forma mas acho que seu problema é bem simples. E outra forma não garante que vai resolver o problema.

Você está em :

```
C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SLN_CAPRO\CAPRO\bin\Debug
```

quando manda acessar:

```
../arquivos/teste.jpg
```

significa que está acessando:

```
C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SLN_CAPRO\CAPRO\bin\arquivos\teste.jpg
```

que não é o que onde você diz que está o arquivo:

```
C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SLN_CAPRO\CAPRO\arquivos\teste.jpg
```

Então o correto seria acessá-lo através de:

```
../../arquivos/teste.jpg
```

Mas você pode querer configurar um ambiente de execução mais complexo com [`ProcessStartInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0):

```
var processo = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo() {
    WorkingDirectory = "../../arquivos",
    FileName = "teste.jpg"
});
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enviroment/ConfigProcess.cs).